# Can I send a message to the owner of a YouTube channel with nothing on it?

Tags: youtube

A YouTube user has placed a comment on a video and I wish to message them without everyone knowing of the conversation as I'll be using my personal story to convey a point in relation to his query.

It's not my channel that he has commented or nor is it his.

When I click on his name it's all pretty bare.

Is there a way I can contact him?

Comment: Your question title is confusing. It sounds like you want to send an empty message, which from your actual question I take not to be the case. So are you simply trying to send a private message to a particular user? Or do you want to send them an anonymous PM?

Comment: Lol why would I want to send an empty email to someone?

Comment: Stranger things have been seen on Stack Exchange. Anyway, you didn't answer the question in my comment.

Comment: Ha I can imagine. Thanks for the answer chap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are asking how to send a PM (private message which only you and the recipient can see) on YouTube.

To send a PM to another YouTube user:

- Create a YouTube/Google+ account if you do not already have one.
- While exploring YouTube, click on the user you want to message. This
  will momentarily cause more info about the user to hover above
  the username but don't click again, just wait and you will be
  directed to the user's channel page.
- Depending on that user's privacy settings, you may see the following links across the bottom of the Channel header:
  **Home  Videos  Playlists Channels Discussion About**
  Click **About**
- Click **Send Message**
- Enter your message and click **Send**

If the user you are trying to send the message to does not have a "confirmed" account, this feature will not be available in their channel.  Your only alternative will be to arrange, initially via public comment, to communicate over another means.  Keep in mind also, if their comment is rather old (a few years at least), they may have posted that comment before Google+ was melded with YouTube, in which case if they have not Created a Google+ account, they may be unable to even make new public YouTube comments. If their comments are more recent, you can obviously rule that out though.

Here is the official [help page](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/57955?hl=en) from Google Support.

Comment: Well explained :)

Comment: Nice one faints cheers